# How can I execute silverlight unit tests from the command line

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, msbuild, continuous-integration

I've a set of tests for a silverlight application that use Silverlight's test framework.  I can execute these from within visual studio and they run beautifully. I can also build my code from outside Visual studio using MSBuild following the tips in Jeff Wilcox's blog post: 
http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/01/silverlight-msbuild-tricks-video/

I would like to execute my unit tests from the command line (Using MSBuild or NAnt etc.) and fail the Build if the tests fail.  This does not appear to be possible with the current Silverlight MSBuild assets.

So my question is:

**How can I execute silverlight unit tests from the command line using a build tool like MSBuild?**

Comment: Good question. This is important for Continuous Integration builds. I'd like to know a good answer too.

Answer (score 7):

I have had success with StatLight.
http://statlight.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

This is a question I posed on the silverlight.net forum and got some response from Jeff Wilcox. I think this problem is still open:

http://silverlight.net/forums/p/57811/166439.aspx

The latest post recommends a promising [powershell solution](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2292)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out project Lighthouse: http://lighthouse.codeplex.com/ (see also [this](http://blog.roboblob.com/2011/03/22/lighthouse_silverlight_unit_test_runner_project_released/) as a reference)

I haven't tried it vs Statlight so I cannot comment on which is better. Come January I will give it a try.